# Getting network error 413 Request Entity Too Large event with size limit settled to 50mb and correct payload size

Tags: node.js, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I'm getting network error `413 Request Entity Too Large`, even when the configured size limit is 50mb and the payload size is a lot of shorter than that.

`Status Code: 413 Request Entity Too Large`

response headers:

```
Connection: close
Content-Length: 585
Content-Type: text/html
Date: Tue, 19 Oct 2021 15:36:06 GMT
Server: nginx/1.20.0
```

request headers:

```
Accept: application/json, text/javascript, */*; q=0.01
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
Accept-Language: en,es-ES;q=0.9,es;q=0.8
Connection: keep-alive
Content-Length: 2072572
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded; charset=UTF-8
Cookie: ...
Host: ...
Origin: ...Referer: http://devxd.us-east-1.elasticbeanstalk.com/admin/post/edit/22/
User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/94.0.4606.81 Safari/537.36
X-Requested-With: XMLHttpRequest
```

in my nginx.config file i have:

```
    files:
   /etc/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf:
     owner: root
     group: root
     mode: "000644"
     content: |
       client_max_body_size 50M;

       # Elastic Beanstalk Managed
     ...
```

**the curious thing is that this config is working fine in prod**

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to update config file to this:

**path** `.platform/nginx/conf.d/elasticbeanstalk/max_bodysize.conf`

**content** `client_max_body_size 50M;`